# I have a survey question in SharePoint 2010 with a Ratings Scale as the response?

Tags: 2010, survey, rating

I want to force the user to respond to this multi-answer question with ONLY one level of scale per response. For example: if the user rates the first response at 1, I want to force the user to use a rating other than 1 on the other responses.

Answer (score 1):

You could code up a presave action in JavaScript to make sure the levels are unique. Or attach a JavaScript  onchanged function to check for duplicates after a user changes a level. Or use JavaScript to convert the input text box to a drop down that displayed only the available choices.